# accessing dummy variable in fortran prevents optimization?

Tags: optimization, fortran

I'm trying to optimize some fortran code and noticed some surprizing behaviour that I'm trying to understand.  progb runs about 3 or 4 times faster than proga.  The only difference is the assignment "d = 2" in progb instead of "d = b" in proga, so naively these should be equivalent:

```
  program proga
  implicit  none

  call hist(2)
  stop
  end

  subroutine hist(b)
  implicit  none
  integer, intent(in):: b
  integer   d,i,p(200000000)

  d = b
  do i=1,200000000
     p(i) = i/d
  end do
  write(*,*) p(1)
  end


  program progb
  implicit  none

  call hist(2)
  stop
  end

  subroutine hist(b)
  implicit  none
  integer, intent(in):: b
  integer   d,i,p(200000000)

  d = 2
  do i=1,200000000
     p(i) = i/d
  end do
  write(*,*) p(1)
  end
```

I compile with "gfortran proga.f -O3" and likewise for progb.  This occurs on gcc version 4.9.2 on Debian as well as gcc version 5.4.0 on cygwin.

When I compile instead without the -O3 flag both run at the same speed, so it sounds like the compiler can't optimize proga as well.  What optimization can't be done on proga, and why?

I've pruned my code down for this post (my actual code does something useful!).  The constant 200000000 should be large enough to give a significant runtime.  The write prevents the loop being optimized away.

Answer (score 4):

The value 2 is a very special value. If the compiler knows that it always divides by 2, it can just shift the bits instead of doing an arithmetic computation. However, in `progb` the compiler must count with any possible integer value so must implement real division, not just a bit shift.

So, accessing the argument does not inhibit any optimization. Using a fixed value allows some specific optimization. Especially if it is a power of 2.

Check the difference at https://godbolt.org/z/TcJxYK

The generic version uses

```
idiv    ecx
```

the version dividing by 2 uses

```
shr     edx, 31
add     eax, edx
sar     eax
```

The `idiv` instruction is much slower than the shifts and addition.

For non-powers of two it is still optimizable, but it generally also involves arithmetic operations as multiplications, additions and subtractions, not just bit shifts. Nevertheless, these are faster than a division. Division is a very slow operation.

---

As steve pointed out, using `-fwhole-program` enables the compiler to compile all units together and also it can assume it does not need to generate the unneeded subroutines.

BTW, for the simplified subroutines I used in the godbolt link above gfortran optimizes out the call to the subroutine even without `-fwhole-program`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Vladimir.  So the compiler isn't smart enough to know that b will always take the value 2 in proga?

Comment: The compiler is plenty smart.  Unfortunately, the programmer is not trying  to help the compiler.  Try making the subroutine a `contain`ed internal subprogram or try using the -fwhole-program option.  `proga` and `hist` are independent scoping units.

Comment: Fantastic, Steve, -fwhole-program does the trick, with both versions running equally fast.  I would add that without -fwhole-program not only powers of 2 run faster in progb - setting d to a large prime is still faster than proga.  So I guess it's the fact that d is known by the compiler to have a particular value (power of 2 or not) that allows the compiler to optimize without -fwhole-program.

Comment: @fredko Even for larger primes it can be well optimized. But it is more then just one bit shift that is so easy to illustrate. It will also some multiplication, which is still faster than a division, but still more than a shift.

Comment: @steve What does `-fwhole-program` do? Do you know the equivalent for ifort?

Comment: @king, `-fwhole-program` tells the compiler that the file contains everything that is needed for compilation.  In this case, `call hist(2)` will mean the compiler knows that `subroutine hist()` is in the file.  When gfortran parses hist(), gfortran can do additional optimizations including in-lining the subroutine.